# How Could I convert a JSON object to image object?

Tags: json, image, discord.py

I've attempted to look this solution up many times, however none of them work. Trying to make a discord bot that uses a JSON storage system. The bot is made in python. I'll show the code where I've tried multiple ways to display a image from the JSON storage. Even Utf-8 and 16 encoding didn't work. So I've randomly been trying just about anything now. It is like this ->

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "Name": "bulbasaur",
  "Image": "https://i.imgur.com/MOQHxZGg.png"
}

JSON above

Python below
@commands.command(name='image_test')
    async def image(self, context,  arg):
        with open('image.json') as image:
            p = json.load(image)
        p['Name'] = arg
        #print(p['Name'])
        #print(p['Image'])

        #with urllib2.urlopen(p['Image']) as i:
            #data = i.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')


        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.title = 'test image'
        embed.set_image(url=requests.get(p['Image']).url)
        await context.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a JSON object is loaded into python, it behaves exactly like a dictionary, with values that can be accessed with keys:

```py
>>> mydict = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> mydict["foo"]
bar
```

The embed's images work purely off of a URL in a string that leads to the source image. You already have the image's URL stored in the json, so all you need to do is use the right key (`"Image"`) to access its URL for the embed:

```py
    @commands.command(name='image_test')
    async def image(self, context,  arg):

        with open('image.json') as image:
            p = json.load(image)

        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.title = 'test image'
        embed.set_image(url=p['Image'])
        await context.send(embed=embed) # edited to use context.send()
```

As a side-note, one thing I noticed was your use of `context.channel.send()`.
The `Context` object inherits from `abc.Messageable`, meaning that you can directly call the `send()` coroutine to send a message to the channel.

---

**References:**

- [Dictionaries in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
- [`Embed.set_image()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image)
- [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)
- [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable)

Comment: I've tried the p['Image'] and it didn't work. Here's the result of it -> [link](https://imgur.com/gallery/0VG2IcW)

Comment: That's an issue on imgur's side I believe, although I might be wrong. I'd recommend just finding another picture if you can - https://i.imgur.com/I2oTNId.png - that one worked for me. I'm not sure why some images don't appear - I've had it happen to me as well. When reading the embed's image's properties, it shows the right url, but it says the width and height are both 0. If I find out anything about why some images don't show, then I'll report back here

Comment: The image I was using had a custom canvas size so that it could adjust the spacing in the embed for the image.

Comment: got it working, just had to reupload the same image and then it started working. Apparently it was due to imgur corrupting the image data for some display types.

Comment: Ahh right, that's good to know, great find! Did you find out what specific display types caused the image to not show? @Nembius

Comment: I didn't really look into that, however, one display type that doesn't work at all... even with just regular discord posting an image is a twitter preview image display type. That's one I know for sure. If that gives you an idea. Like if you download the preview image and then try to manual upload it on discord without a bot or anything... it wont show the image.

Comment: What I'm thinking is if an image's internal data is off even slightly from a regular image that discord is used to; it will treat it like a regular file instead... thus no display.